# Can't load JSON-type message in client

Tags: python, sockets

I can't load JSON-type message with dictionary inside when client receives it from server

Dictionary contains: message, sender address, time of sending
When i dump dictionary to JSON and send it to client, client tries to load this dict, so he can't use data from dictionary from server and print it to user
Also, when client sending message he can write "/r" to receive data from server, that means client can receive big data at one time.
This is only parts of code with sending and receiving data from server and in client

SERVER

```py
    def serialize_data(self, sending_time, message, address,):
        message_dict = {
            'sending_time': sending_time,
            'message': message,
            'sender_address': address
            }
        serialized_dict = dumps(message_dict)
        return serialized_dict

    def send_messages(self, data_dict, address):
        if enable_log:
            message = f'{self.get_time()}, {data_dict["message"]}, {address}'
            self.save_log(message, 'a')
        message = self.serialize_data(self.get_time(), data_dict['message'], address)
        for client in self.connections_list:
            message = dumps(message)
            client.sendall(bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'))
```

CLIENT

```py
    def receive_data(self,):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.sock.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
                print(data)
                data_dict = loads(data)
                for d in data_dict:
                    d = loads(d)
                    d = f"{d['sending_time']} {d['sender_address']} - {d['message']}"
                    print(d)
            except timeout:
                break
```

I getting this in client when i trying to receive data from server:

```
"{\"sending_time\": \"2019-05-17 | 21:16:32 \", \"message\": \"connected!\", \"sender_address\": \"127.0.0.1\"}""{\"sending_time\": \"2019-05-17 | 21:16:33 \", \"message\": \"abcd\", \"sender_address\": \"127.0.0.1\"}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are calling json.dumps() twice.

```
def serialize_data(self, sending_time, message, address,):
    message_dict = {
        'sending_time': sending_time,
        'message': message,
        'sender_address': address
        }
    serialized_dict = dumps(message_dict) # -------------> first time
    return serialized_dict


def send_messages(self, data_dict, address):
    if enable_log:
        message = f'{self.get_time()}, {data_dict["message"]}, {address}'
        self.save_log(message, 'a')
    message = self.serialize_data(self.get_time(), data_dict['message'], address)
    for client in self.connections_list:
        message = dumps(message)  # ------------------> Second time
        client.sendall(bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'))
```

Removing either one of them should fix it.